# Как в коде отменить перенос текста в ячейке, и как задавать ширину определенного столбца?

Tags: vba, libre-office

```
Sub jurnal
Dim oDoc As Object
Dim oSheet As Object
Dim Cell As Object

   oDoc = ThisComponent
   oSheet = oDoc.getCurrentController().ActiveSheet

   oSheet.Rows.insertByIndex(0,1)
   
   oSheet.Columns.insertByIndex(3, 1)
   
   Cell = oSheet.getCellRangeByName("A1")
   Cell.String = "Журнал телефонной базы предприятия"
   Cell.CharWeight = com.sun.star.awt.FontWeight.BOLD
   Cell.CharHeight = 14
       Range("A1").WrapText= False
   
   Cell = oSheet.getCellRangeByName("D2")
   Cell.String = "Номер телефона" End Sub
```

Код на команде Range("A1").WrapText= False выдает ошибку. Может можно отменить перенос текста другим методом?
И ещё столбец ячейки D2 сильно растягивается. Надо уменьшить ширину. Как это сделать?

Comment: `Cell.IsTextWrapped = False`?

Answer (score 0):

Можете попробовать подобным способом (проверил - работает).

```
Sub jurnal()
   
   Range("A1").Value = "Журнал телефонной базы предприятия"
   Range("A1").WrapText = False
   Columns(1).AutoFit
   'или Columns("B").ColumnWidth = 25
End Sub
```